# Can't use WebElement Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

On using

```
WebElement img = driver.findElement(By.id("abc"));
```

I get following error -

```
WebElement img = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('captchaimg'));
           ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

The packages that i have installed -

selenium-webdriver

chromdriver

webdriver

**Versions -**

- node 8.11.2
- selenium-webdriver 4.0.0-alpha.1
- chromedriver 2.38 (downloaded from [here](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html))

Comment: Show your nodejs  and selenium-webdriver version,  you need to use higher nodejs

Comment: @yong i have added the versions of all the packages iused, if u need amthing else u can ask

Comment: I updated the answer from cruisepandey.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
   withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
   build();

driver.get('your URL');  
//WebElement img = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('abc')); 
// We can't use `WebElement` at here, in javascript, 
// we can't declare the type of variable like Java.
// In your case, JavaScript will treat `WebElement` as variable name,
// Because there already has a variable name, JavaScript don't know 
// how to deal with the following `img`.
// You should change `WebElement` to `var` or `const`

var img = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('abc'));
```

Comment: not working still same error, can u post the packages that need to be installed too, maybe i missed one

Comment: Node built-in package manager , you can use npm install selenium-webdriver command

Comment: i am using it too but idk why its not working...btw i have added full error msg, please check if it helps

Comment: @yong : sounds logical to me ! monster give a shot ! It might work !